# How can I process multiple requests in a batch operation in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a task to implement group transfer to the database, but I have encountered a problem, I already receive a List with prepared queries, and I don’t understand much about how to put them in one Batch, I’m not sure that my solution is correct, so I ask those who know people asking for help

```
public class SQLPreparedStatement {
    private final Connection connection;
    private final List<PreparedStatement> input = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<PreparedStatement> output = new ArrayList<>();

    public SQLPreparedStatement(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public ResultSet create(boolean next) throws SQLException {
        return execute(next) instanceof ResultSet data ? data : null;
    }

    public Object execute(boolean next) throws SQLException {
        for (PreparedStatement statement : input) {
            if (statement.getMetaData() != null)
                return statement.executeQuery();
            else {
                output.add(statement);
                if (output.size() >= 50 || next) {
                    update();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void update() throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement result = this.connection.prepareStatement("");
        result.clearParameters();
        result.close();

        for (PreparedStatement update : output) {
            result.addBatch(update.toString());
            result.clearParameters();
            result.close();

            output.remove(update);
        }

        result.executeLargeBatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep closing the statement? Why do you keep removing from the collection you’re iterating over? What happened when you ran this? What is your question?

Comment: This is not meant deragatory, disrespectful. But you should first play with examples of JDBC. A list of prepared statements is rare. If the statements are interconnected, things should done in a (huge) compound SQL statement with joins and subqueries.

Comment: I would be rather derogatory of whoever gave you this task. A JDBC batch consists of a number of executions of the *same* prepared statement with different parameters. A list of prepared statements just needs executing individually, but as @JoopEggen says, it is rare.

Comment: In any JDBC-compliant driver implementation, you wouldn't even be able to call `addBatch(String)` on a `PreparedStatement` (it's specified to throw an exception, always!), so I guess you're using MySQL. In addition, JDBC implementations will not necessarily have a usable `toString()` on their `PreparedStatement` implementation. It might return anything from the prepared statement with the original statement text (including parameter placeholders), to the default `Object#toString()` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume:

- You have a list of database tranfer statements, without dynamic parameters.
- They should be executed as a whole.

Then one needs:

1. Open the connection, *transactionally*. That is an SQL `commit` at the end and on failure a `rollback`.
2. Execute every statement separately.
3. Commit.
4. Close the connection.

There is not JDBC batch processing involved. Which means executing the same `PreparedStatement` with *different parameters* at every step.

A tip: use **try-with-resources** with JDBC, providing automatic closing, even on break/return/exception. For almost every JDBC class:

```
try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
    List<MyData> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        MyData record = ... rs ...;
        result.add(record);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here a query example, you probably deal with `executeUpdate`.

---

Of course if all the statements are actually the same varying on parameters, you would have one single PreparedStatement with a list of parameter packs. And then `addBatch`es till `executeBatch`.

Comment: Indeed, a transaction seems to be what is really required. The code that allegedly produces this list of prepared statements is the code that should execute them. There is no point whatsoever in just producing the list and handing it off to some other piece of code that just has to traverse it.